# Lookup / Join with LINQ-to-Entities in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a database that has two tables: Order and Product. This database is exposed via an Entity Data Model and LINQ-to-Entities.

I have a product ID and I want to get all of the Order objects that reference the Product. I would like to learn how to do this with LINQ. I know I can query the products

```
int productID = GetProductID();
using (DatabaseContext database = new DatabaseContext())
{
  var products = from product in database.Products
               where product.ProductID = productID
               select product;

}
```

I know this LINQ query get me all of the products with a specific product ID. However, I want the Order objects. I was trying to figure out to do a Join and get the just the Order objects. I do not care about the products as I have the product id. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: The `Orders` table isn't exposed directly by the data context?

Comment: Is it a Many-to-Many relationship between Products and Orders?

Comment: You should have Order.ProductID.

Comment: What relevant properties do order and product have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var orders = from product in database.Products
            join order in database.Orders on product.Key equals order.KeyField 
           where product.ProductID == productID
           select order;
```

Comment: Note that that could give the same order multiple times if one order contains the same product multiple times. That may not be an issue, but it's worth knowing about.

Answer (score 1):

Normally an `Order` would have a relationship to the products, allowing you to write:

```
var orders = from order in database.Orders
             where order.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == productID)
             select order;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this would be done like this :

For the sake of simplicity : `[TABLE] <key/relation>`

```
[Products]-<productId>-[OrderedProducts]-<orderId>-[Orders]

var result = 
from op in OrderedProducts
join o in Orders on op.OrderId equals o.Id
join p in Products on op.ProductId equals p.Id
select p
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (depending on properties you have):

```
context.Orders.Where(order => order.ProductId == myProduct.Id);
```